# Get Date from DateTime without ToShortDateString

Tags: c#, datetime

I am searching for this for about 2 hours and I don't have any ideas anymore. 
The problem is I have a DateTime object and I need only the date part from it.

I tried

1. `data.Date`
2. create a new DateTime object like this

   `var x = new DateTime(data.Year,data.Months,data.Day)`
3. I tried like this

   `DateTime.Parse(data.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))`

NOTE: After getting the date part only,  data needs to remain DateTime ( not string ), so I can not use `ToShortDateString()`

Comment: What's wrong with `.Date`?

Comment: There is no Date class in .net, only DateTime. If you set a DateTime without a time (as in your second example) then the time will default to 0:00:00. Why is it a problem that you have a time in you DateTime? If you really need only a date, create you own Date struct.

Comment: The DateTime object always has a time component, even if there is no time associated. There is no Date class/struct, and there is no Time class/struct. It's unnecessary.  If you want to display only the date part of a DateTime then use the format strings. .ToString("d") or .ToString("D") should do the trick.

Comment: @SLaks: I assume the problem is that `.Date` returns a `DateTime` which, of course, has a time (set to 00:00:00). Why this is a problem is anybody's guess.

Comment: The problem is I am using KnockoutJS and I am bindind an input value to that DateTime object. The value of the input it is always like this  : 2012-10-10T12:21:32   . I need to show it exactly like this : 2012-10-10

Comment: @CosminGrigore, there is no any property to format the input value in KnockoutJS.

Comment: @Anandkumar  I know. That's why I am trying to do this from server side

Comment: Just call myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").

Comment: I said I need it like a DateTime object after conversion.

Comment: @Cosmin Grigore You're downvoting instead of describe something more about ur problem...

Comment: What do you want to know  ? I think I explained exactly what I need. The date part from a DateTime object without switching it to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want some object, witch always return date in `2012-10-10` format from `.ToString()`, you can use this struct

```
struct Date
{
    private DateTime dateTime;
    public Date(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        this.dateTime = dateTime.Date;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
}
```