# Is there a way to convert a date format when referencing it from an external service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, date-formatting

I am trying to convert a date from `19/10/2012 00:00:00` to `19/10/2012`. I can't state the date type in the viewmodel like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor) as code is as below:

Viewmodel:

```
public Appointment Appointment {get; set;}
```

I am aware that mapping is an option but would like to see if an alternate option is available as this will make reusing the code easier and if the service changes at all then mapping will complicate things.

Mock service example:

```
public class Appointment
    {
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }  
        [DataMember]
        public Identifier AppointmentIdentifier { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [DataMember]

    ...etc
```

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be your question here? Seems somewhat similar. I'm calling a dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975381/get-date-from-datetime-without-toshortdatestring

Comment: I have to ask why are you not just assigning it to the DateTime as is?

Comment: A datetime **isn't** a string like "19/10/2012 00:00:00" or "19/10/2012". These are string representations (or serializations) of a datetime. You can't have half an object. DateTime. Date. Time. Perhaps you want to affect the serialization process somehow. Perhaps you should deal with this the other end, but you can't lop fields/properties off a type from the BCL.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is that you define a field like _AppointmentDate and then, in its property return whatever date format you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning the `AppointmentDate` as a string and then casting it back to `DateTime`?